# Liferay: Ckeditor Toolbar Icons are blocked by CSP in TEST and PROD environment

Tags: image, ckeditor, icons, liferay, toolbar

I have used ckeditor in Liferay before, but never came across the problem I have now: The toolbar icons from ckeditor are not displayed - but only TEST and PROD environment. Locally it works.

Here is the toolbar:

[image]

The error message in the browsers console says:

> Refused to load the image "" because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https:".

I have already research that this might be a CSP related problem and can be solved with e.g. `img-src *`. But how do I set this in Liferay 7.3?

Comment: could it be a mixed-content issue, e.g. you're accessing the page through https, but it tries to load resources through http, which is rightfully rejected?

Comment: Yes thats correct, but how can I fix this?

Comment: Go https all the way. How exactly completely depends on your setup - e.g. with/without reverse proxy, where do you terminate https, etc. Alternatively, (for your test system only), go http all the way. As long as you don't try to load http resources into a https page, this CSP will not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i will check this.